# PyQt item view custom drag and drop

Tags: python, pyqt, drag-and-drop, pyqt4

I am working on a custom drag-drop implementation in a QTableView. When I drag a cell and drop it on another cell I want to manually change some data in the model based on what was dragged and where it was dropped. How can I do this? I've been reading through all Qt documentation but I am utterly lost, and in particular with drag-drop it seems that the C++ to PyQt conversion is a little less intuitive.

Basically what I need is when I drop I want to know what cells were initially dragged, and where they were dropped. Where my confusion lies seems to be with QMimeData. From what I can tell when the drag starts, the drag event receives the right MIME data but I don't know how to get at it in PyQt (been able to do this sort of thing with text and urls in the past but I'm lost when it comes to an item view). I also need to know where I'm dropping to. I guess I could do an "item at cursor pos" but I assume this data already exists in the drop event and I just need to figure out how to query it.

Here's a simple example:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class TableView(QtGui.QTableView):
     def __init__(self, parent=None):
         QtGui.QTreeWidget.__init__(self, parent)
         self.setDragEnabled(True)
         self.setDropIndicatorShow(True)
         self.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
         self.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)
         self.setSelectionBehavior(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)

     def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        # I want to do cool things with the dragged cells, and I need to know where they dropped!
        print(event.mimeData().formats()) # this tells me that I shuld get some sort of "qabstractitemmodeldatalist". Sounds promising...
        print(event.mimeData().data("application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist")) # this gives me an interesting looking QByteArray but I have no idea what to do with it...
        event.accept()

class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        model.insertRow(0, QtGui.QStandardItem("C"))
        model.insertRow(0, QtGui.QStandardItem("B"))
        model.insertRow(0, QtGui.QStandardItem("A"))

        table = TableView(self)
        table.setModel(model)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Dialog()
ex.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not know where it was dragged since the mimeData does not have that information but you can get the data dragged, for that we created a temporary model where we will establish the mimeData emulating the same behavior of the drag. To obtain where it was dropped, the position that comes as part of the event must be used together with indexAt(), thus obtaining the QModelIndex:

```py
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class TableView(QtGui.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QTreeWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
        self.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
        self.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)
        self.setSelectionBehavior(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if self.viewport().rect().contains(event.pos()):
            fake_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
            fake_model.dropMimeData(
                event.mimeData(), event.dropAction(), 0, 0, QtCore.QModelIndex()
            )
            print("from:")
            for r in range(fake_model.rowCount()):
                for c in range(fake_model.columnCount()):
                    ix = fake_model.index(r, c)
                    print(ix.data())
            to_index = self.indexAt(event.pos())
            if to_index.isValid():
                print("to:", to_index.data())
        super(TableView, self).dropEvent(event)


class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        for letter in "ABC":
            model.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem(letter))

        table = TableView()
        table.setModel(model)

        lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(table)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Dialog()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks, I would have never thought to use a dummy model!

Comment: You know, maybe the mimeData doesn't have the dragged cells but I just figured out that I can capture them by storing `self.selectedIndexes()` in the dragEnterEvent.

Comment: @Spencer What you indicate is correct, the mimetypes is a protocol for transporting data, and in the case of "application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist" only transports the information of the roles. Your method only works if the drop-and-drop is the same view. If you want another view to pass that information you should add more data to the mimedata when it starts to drag. In addition, the concept of row and column does not exist in all views or sources of mimedata.

Comment: Makes sense. Luckily in this case I know it is going to be in the same view, so I have it easy!